# Safari - Children elements height more than parent

Tags: html, css, safari

I have 3 div, it looks like this:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="header"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Height of .parent is 100%
Height of .header is 50px
Height of .content is 100%

In Chrome it works fine but in Safari, the height of .content and .header is more than .parent height.

For example, if .parent is 600px. Height of .header and .content is 700px.

I've tried with cal(100% - 50px) then it works for Safari but in Chrome, the .content height is shorter.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us your CSS ?

Comment: yes please show us  the code

Answer (score 1):

It is calc not cal.
I think this is not an error because you have 100% height of content which will become the same size of parent and addition height of header that is why he height of .content and .header is more than .parent height.

check this pen, calc is working fine: https://codepen.io/adrianrios/pen/OmRXpE

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent{
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  background: pink;
}

.header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content{
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```